# Sending JSON to PHP using Android

Tags: php, android, json, post

I am trying to send JSON to php and store the data that sent
but I cant make it work

my Android Code

```
  public void sendToServer(String txt) throws JSONException{

            String path = "http://10.0.0.6:8888/json.php";

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                                                                                    // Limit
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(path);
                json.put("text", txt);
                Log.i("jason Object", json.toString()); //This print the data perfectly 
                post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
                post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                Log.i("Done", "DONE 1");

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));
                Log.i("Done", "DONE 2");

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myjson", json.toString()));
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 


                Log.i("Done", "DONE 3");

                response = client.execute(post);

                /* Checking response */
                if (response != null) {
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); // Get the
                                                                        // data in
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // entity
                    String a = convertStreamToString(in);
                    Log.i("Read from Server", a);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                     }
```

and my php code

```
<?php  

$decoded = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myjson']));
if($decoded)
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root') 
       or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_select_db('deaf',$con);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO text
VALUES ('".$decoded->{'text'}"')");
mysql_close($con);
$posts = array(1);
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts)); 

else
echo "error";
  ?>
```

the insert statement doesn't work , i spent hours trying to fix it , nothing worked 
please help me , thanks

Comment: What you're getting in your `in` variable of Java? replace your templating `if` with `if {} else {}`. It just works for 1 line code and you're having 10lines here in that if. It wouldn't work.

Comment: sorry , these are from reading from the server , not sending to it , I have issue in sending , thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with this.

1. You seem to just be cramming the json into arbitrary parts of your code (json header, a never used StringEntity, the myjson url-encoded form field).  I would recommend simply making the body of the request the JSON document.  However, there are other approaches, so let's try to get the `myjson` working.  If you do, I would change the name to something like `document`.  It doesn't  need to be in the header, and you can remove StringEntity.
2. There are very few correct uses for [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).  You should not have to run it on form input.  If you do, that may mean `magic_quotes` is enabled. magic_quotes has been removed from PHP (5.4 and later) and should never be used.
3. I recommend you use prepared statements.  If not, you should use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).  Otherwise, you will be vulnerable to SQL injection.
4. You can simplify the object access.  So the code should be:

   `mysql_query("INSERT INTO text VALUES ('" . mysql_real_scape_string($decoded->text) . "')");`

If the insert statement fails, please post what the errors are, including [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php).

Comment: Thanks for the reply , just a question , the myjson or document , how the json object will be if I use it ??

Comment: I'm saying replace `myjson` with `document` on both client and server.

Comment: I know , but whats the JSON will look
{"text": "sometext"}
where is the document in this object or this for handling only ?
sorry but i am really new on this :)

Comment: You're using UrlEncodedFormEntity, so it will be like `document={"text": "sometext"}` except the part after the equals sign is url-encoded.